# Handling popups to pass details Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium

[image]I am trying to pass Details of a user, when a popup shows up. Details include First Name, Last Name, emailid etc.
I know how to send keys to a popup but not in different boxes(Like you need to enter last name press tab, then go to the second name). I am trying to inspect element but all I get is the CSS code, not any HTML code.
The C# code I have written is:

```
var w = new WebDriverWait(Driver.Instance, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
var copy = w.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("copyButton")));
copy.Click();
IAlert alert = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.AlertIsPresent());
```

I have no idea how to proceed.
Can anyone please help?
Thank you.

Comment: You mean when you click on `copyButton` button the form popup will occurs. Right??...are you sure it is Javascript alert popup???..could you share that popup as well with screenshot???

Comment: It is a window popup.

Comment: Yes if possible HTML or screenshot..

Comment: I shared the popup window :)

Comment: Ok try with my answer.. and let me know if any problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shoul try as below :-

```
 string mainWindow = driver.WindowHandle;

var w = new WebDriverWait(Driver.Instance, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
var copy = w.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("copyButton")));
copy.Click();
driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles.Last());
 //do your stuff for filling the form in popup window

//then close the popup window
 driver.Close();

 //Switch back to main window
driver.SwitchTo().Window(mainWindow);

 // now do your stuff to main window
```

Hope it helps..:)

Comment: Hey thank you so much, do you know how we should enter stuff in the popup window, like passing the first name or last name, because when I am trying to inspect element in the popup, its not showing me any.

Comment: Same as you are doing with main window..just go to find element by locator and use sendKeys...:)

Comment: You should try by right click and view page source and then try to inspect

Comment: Thats what I am doing, but the problem I am facing is suppose if I try to pass the LastName in the popup, the field name in the popup and the main window is same, so instead of passing to the popup it is passing to the main window, same happens to the other fields as well like the first name, userid because the field name in the popup and the mainbox is same.

Comment: @Adrija Means your still in the main window..once print the size of total window after click as `driver.WindowHandles.Size()` and let me know the result..

Comment: So I did what you said, but unfortuneatly I am getting error which says: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
'ReadOnlyCollection<string>' does not contain a definition for 'Size' and no extension method 'Size' accepting a first argument of type 'ReadOnlyCollection<string>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) IbankAuto

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118040/discussion-between-adrija-and-saurabh-gaur).